# Error Message when starting Update: Failed to load the package list

Tags: 12.04, updates

Message says:

```
Failed to load the package list

This is a serious problem. Try again later. If this problem appears again, please report an error to the developers.  
Click details, which says:

E:Type 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/madman2k/ubuntu' is not known on line 61 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Tried this solution:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf  
sudo apt-get update
```

However, when entering the first command, it hits back an error:

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists': Is a directory
```

Some people are suggesting that I change settings in the update manager. I unfortunately can't, since the update manager closes each time I get the error.

Any other way to remove that package?

Comment: Please use your existing account to perform edits so they do not have to go through the suggested edit queue.

Answer (score 0):

Open update manager, click on settings, open the "other software" tab, delete the ppa.launchpad.net/madman2k/ubuntu entry.  Try again.

This usually happens when the ppa is no longer required and has been removed, or if it not available or required for a new Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because the `madman2k` user's repositories have been removed from the PPA system. Try vising http://ppa.launchpad.net/madman2k/.

All you need to do is remove the line(s) for this PPA in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Also, use `sudo apt-add-repository` in the future, so that your repositories are added into `/etc/apt/sources.d/`. This way, you can remove an invalid repository such as this one with just `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:madman2k/ubuntu`.